# App with DrawerLayout crashes when app opens

Tags: android, kotlin

I use a drawer-layout, with a RecyclerView, where I customize each view. I'm not sure where the problem lies, just that crashes as soon as the app starts. At the moment, there is'nt even much displayed. Just the UI. At first, I first it was the recyclerView which cause the problem, but then I removed that and it still did not work.

activity_main.xml, which has the drawer, toolbar, and lots of other things

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_activity_content_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_appbarlayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:weightSum="1"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_main_content_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:clipToPadding="false">
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_layout"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var drawerLayout: DrawerLayout
    private lateinit var adapter: NavigationRVAdapter
    lateinit var  navigation_rv: RecyclerView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)
        navigation_rv.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        navigation_rv.setHasFixedSize(true)
     }}
```

EDITED:
Logcat

```
2020-10-22 19:33:44.579 8049-8049/com.example.inkrement2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.inkrement2, PID: 8049
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.inkrement2/com.example.inkrement2.MainActivity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property navigation_rv has not been initialized
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property navigation_rv has not been initialized
        at com.example.inkrement2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7009)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7000)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: Can you post the crash log from the logcat?

Comment: Do you mean what I've just posted under Log?

Comment: So, I've figured out what logcat is and posted it :)

Comment: Ok it looks like you have not defined your recyclerview in the onCreate method. navigation_rv = findViewById(R.id.navigation_rv);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error say you don't initialize the RecyclerView. In order to fix that you need to put a recycler view object in your xml layout.

Something like this:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
         android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         tools:listitem="@layout/recycler_view_item"
         android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

And then initialize in the onCreate Method:

```
 recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
```

Comment: If you have another's problems to with the recyclerView, tell me and i'm provide a full implementation.